# Object options upon creating a new mesh don't show up anymore (vertices etc)

Tags: interface

Usually when creating a new mesh, say a cylinder, you can pick the number of vertices.

This option does not appear to me anymore. How can I bring it back?

Answer (score 2):

Ok so if anyone else ever has this problem just click the little plus sign on the bottom of your toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

The panel that displays the options remembers the scrolling settings from its last content.

So if last time it had to display a long menu (*e.g.* Add > Torus) and you scrolled all the way down, and this time it's displaying a short menu (*e.g.* Add > Cube) you may need to **scroll up to reveal the new content**.

[image]

Comment: This is not the case, unfortunately, the "Add Torus" menu does not even show up. Same goes for each and every mesh object.

Comment: Sorry if it sounds dumb, but is it minimized? Like, it shows the "Add Torus" title but not the content? If you could edit your questions by adding a blend file (through [this service](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)) it would be easier to troubleshoot